# Regular expression: Define max length of string, with repeated groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

The title might be confusing, but I will try to use some examples to explain.
This is the current expression I've made.

```
^([A-ZÆØÅ][a-zæøå]+[\s-]{1}){2,20}$
```

I want an expression that will match these:
So the general rule is,

-Every word has to start with a capital letter

-Following a capital letter can only be small letters

-There can be max one - or whitespace after each other

And the hard part,
in every combination of these, I want the final line to be a maximum of 20 chars

I want an expression that will match these:

```
April-Can Æøå
An-An-An An An-An
Aaaaabbbbbcccccddddd
Aaa
```

Non-matching

```
andkas
Andfak-lkakad
AppleApple
Carrotcarrotcarrotcarrotcarrotcarrot
Banana- Banana
Apple-apple-apple-apple-apple banana banana apple carrot
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use lookahead:

```
^(?=.{2,20}$)[A-ZÆØÅ][a-zæøå]+(?:[\s-][A-ZÆØÅ][a-zæøå]+)*$
```

Where:

`(?=.{2,20}$)` makes sure you have 2 to 20 char in tyhe string.
then you have a word that starts with capital letter eventually followed by a space or a dash and another word. It may have several words

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^([A-ZÆØÅ][a-zæøå]{1,19}[\s-])*[A-ZÆØÅ][a-zæøå]{1,19}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qR2oI9/3)

Comment: It matches string longer than 20 char.

Comment: The first group is unlimited in length :-(

Comment: Sorry but it isn't correct. OP wants the whole line to be less than 20 char.

Comment: Oh I think I got confused with **I want the final line to be a maximum of 20 chars** What exactly is **final line** here?

Comment: Oh, sorry for being late to the party, @M42 is correct, I meant that I want the whole line to be a maximum of 20 chars. But thanks for the help :)!